# Who is responsible to set the process name?

Tags: linux

I am working on a existing linux based script where it contains the following content

```
pid=`jps | grep TestServer | awk '{print $1}'`
kill -9 $pid
```

I understand that this will kill this process named 'TestServer'

I am new to Linux and i am trying to understand the script , so please excuse if this is a dumb question .

Please tell me  **Who is responsible to set the Process name "TestServer"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) don't have any name. It has a (positive) unique number, called its *pid* (process id).

Almost all processes are started -from their parent process- by the [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) system call documented in the [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page (sometimes, [vfork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/vfork.2.html) might be used). A forked process is nearly identical to its parent (it executes the same binary). To execute a new program, the [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall is used inside some process.

However, a process does execute some program, which does have a name (since it exists in the filesystem). You can find much more about processes thru the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) pseudo-file system. Of course, several processes could execute the same program. You could try `ls -l /proc/self/` to list the pseudofiles related to your process (the one executing that `ls` command). You might have fun trying `cat /proc/self/maps`. And `/proc/1234/` tells you about process of pid 1234.

The `pkill`, `pgrep`, `pidof` utilities are using `/proc`.

I suggest you to read a good book on [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) -on paper- and on [advanced Linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) -on the web-; Read also about [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), also the [wikipage on syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

Your script is not right in using directly `kill -9`. It should try first `kill -TERM` then `kill -QUIT` (to let the program terminates nicely, e.g. cleaning temporary files, etc...) and only at last `kill -KILL` (i.e. `kill -9`). You could read the [kill(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html) man page (and also [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page).

#### addenda

<sup>(added in july 2014)</sup>

On Linux, you could use the Linux-specific [pthread_setname_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) function to set a short name of a thread (not a process)

Answer (score 3):

The name comes from the name given to the program. So whatever the file containing the executable is called. If the file is called fred, the process name will be fred.

A better way to kill the process by name is to use pkill.

```
pkill TestServer
```